# Working with Mentor Graphics xPCB Planner\xPCB Layout and OrCAD

Tags: pcb-design, schematics, layout, orcad, eda

I'm working with Mentor Graphics xPCB Planner (very similar to xPCB Layout) for placement and OrCAD Capture CIS 16.5 for schematic design.
I'm interested in working with both tools in parallel, where I can select a component in OrCAD and see where it is located in xPCB Planner.
I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm interested in working with both tools in parallel, where I can
> select a component in OrCAD and see where it is located in xPCB
> Planner.

I think it is not possible to accomplish what you're asking, both the soft-wares are different CAD soft-wares. If you have designed the schematic and board file using the same CAD software package then it possible.